# Display Multidimensional array into table row individually in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, multidimensional-array

I have an array like this (displayed below), I want to display related information individually in a table row which image given below.

```
Array
(
[recent_task_of_developers] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 1
                [name] => Kazi nayem
                [project_name] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [project_name] => Nayem Book House (BBH)
                            )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [project_name] => Nayem Book House (BBH)
                            )

                        [2] => Array
                            (
                                [project_name] => Nayem Book House (BBH)
                            )

                        [3] => Array
                            (
                                [project_name] => Nayem Book House (BBH)
                            )

                    )

            )



        [2] => Array
            (
                [id] => 32
                [name] => Nayem
                [project_name] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [project_name] => Nayem - MasForce
                            )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [project_name] => Nayem - MasForce
                            )

                        [2] => Array
                            (
                                [project_name] => Nayem
                            )

                        [3] => Array
                            (
                                [project_name] => Nayem Book House (BBH)
                            )

                        [4] => Array
                            (
                                [project_name] => Nayem Book House (BBH)
                            )

                        [5] => Array
                            (
                                [project_name] => Nayem - MasForce
                            )

                        [6] => Array
                            (
                                [project_name] => Nayem Book House (BBH)
                            )

                        [7] => Array
                            (
                                [project_name] => Nayem - MasForce
                            )

                        [8] => Array
                            (
                                [project_name] => Nayem - MasForce
                            )

                        [9] => Array
                            (
                                [project_name] => Nayem - MasForce
                            )

                        [10] => Array
                            (
                                [project_name] =>  - MasForce
                            )

                        [11] => Array
                            (
                                [project_name] =>  - MasForce
                            )

                        [12] => Array
                            (
                                [project_name] =>  - MasForce
                            )

                        [13] => Array
                            (
                                [project_name] =>  - MasForce
                            )

                        [14] => Array
                            (
                                [project_name] => Nayem - MasForce
                            )

                        [15] => Array
                            (
                                [project_name] => Nayem Book House (BBH)
                            )

                        [16] => Array
                            (
                                [project_name] => Nayem Book House (BBH)
                            )

                        [17] => Array
                            (
                                [project_name] => Nayem Book House (BBH)
                            )

                        [18] => Array
                            (
                                [project_name] => Nayem Book House (BBH)
                            )

                    )

            )
```

I want to display this array like this image in a table.

[image]

Comment: Whatever you do don't save multi-values in one column like a CSV array

Comment: I see you received an answer, but so you know, we like posters to get into the habit of showing what they have tried. It is very good practice to do so!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
foreach($recent_task_of_developers as $developers)
{
   foreach($developers as $developer)
   {
       $id = $developer['id'];
       $name = $developer['name'];

       foreach($developers['project_name'] as $projects)
       {
           // $projects['project_name']; will contain the projects name in it
           // put your table html accordingly
       }
   }
}
```

I think it will solve your problem.

Comment: That's great :)
Just accept my answer and upvote it :P

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($recent_tasks as $tasks){
 foreach($tasks as $task){
   echo $tasks['name']; // You can add style and html code here inside the string
   foreach($task['project_name'] as $project){
     echo $project;
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below code..

```
<table border="1">
<tr>

<td>Name</td>
<td>Project Name</td>
</tr>

<?php 
foreach($recent_task_of_developers as $developers)
{
?>
<tr>
<?php 
   foreach($developers as $developer)
   {
       $id = $developer['id'];
       $name = $developer['name'];
 ?>
 <td><?php echo $name; ?></td>

 <?php 
    if (!empty($developers['project_name']))
    {
            $numItems = count($developers['project_name']); // counting total projects
            $i = 0;
        foreach($developers['project_name'] as $projects)
            {
                $comma = ',';
                if(++$i === $numItems) 
                {
                    $comma = '';
                }
?>
    <td><?php echo $projects['project_name'] . $comma ; ?></td>
<?php 
            }
    }
    else
    {
?>
    <td></td>
<?php 
    }

   }
 ?>
</tr>
 <?php 
}
?>

</table>
```